# An app that just reads a bar code

Tags: ipad, barcode, reader

I want to develop an app that just reads a bar code. I don't want it to go off to a website or shop or anything. Just read it! It must run on iPad Air. I have seen zbar and a few other suggestions but I want to be sure which one I should use/how to start. Can someone who has done this type of thing help please?

Comment: Stack overflow is not for opinion based questions. It is for code corrections. You will need to do your own research and post here once you have code that you need help with. Basically you should never post with posting your code also. Because that is the first this you will be asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the sample code here that describes iOS native code detection and usage: http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx

When you've progressed to needing something this doesn't accomplish, you will likely have the vocabulary to better describe what you need, what you've tried, and how it has failed for you.